# Rulings on Doubts or Uncertainty

Tags: fatwa, doubts

In case of illegal Intercourse in Islam. If a person doesn't remember, uncertain, doubts or is unsure whether the action of penetration took place. Does the person still need to offer expiation or a sincere repentance made in past is enough?

It is not that the person was intoxicated rather it was long time ago. There was just touching or pressing of private parts. Since the ruling is only on tip of penis it is really hard to tell whether it penetrated or not if one didn't saw.

Answer (score -1):

Unless suffering from Alzheimer desease, if a person doesn't remember, doubts or is unsure whether the action of penetration took place in case of illegal intercourse, isn't it likely that the person is a liar or was totally drunk?

Acting according to illegal intercourse is adequate. Offering expiation and (not or) repenting should be adequate. God knows all.

Comment: Maybe there was just intimacy and the person afterwards made sincere repentance and got on right path and now Shaytan is just whispering something happened.